# React Native navigation: Screen not updating after login attempt

Tags: typescript, react-native, stack-navigator

So I am trying to make a login screen and a home page. If the login button is pressed the requireauth component switches to comp. But I found out that that function is not updating when the button is pressed.

```
import {View, Text, Button, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

var loggedIn = false;

function RequireAuth(Comp: any) {
console.log("requirecomp", loggedIn)
return(
\<View\>
{loggedIn === true
? <Comp/\>
: <LoginPage/\>
}
\<View\>
)
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function App() {
return (
<NavigationContainer\>
<Stack.Navigator\>
<Stack.Screen name="Home"\>
{props => <RequireAuth {...props} Comp={HomePage}\>}
<Stack.Screen\>
<Stack.Navigator\>
<NavigationContainer\>
);
}

function HomePage() {
return(
<View\>
<Text\>This is the home page<Text\>
<View\>
)
}

function LoginPage() {
return(
<View\>
<Text\>This is the login page<Text\>
<Button title='Log In Please' onPress={() => {console.log("pressed"); loggedIn=true;}}\>
</View\>
)
}
```

I printed the variable loggedIn but it did not change after pressing the button. I found posts that offered a different solution, by handling the login step differently, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in the way I intended.

Answer (score 0):

`loggedIn` needs to be in a global state. This can be implemented for example using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Here is the simplified version how to used it:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext(false)

function Toolbar({login}) {
  const loggedIn = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <Button title={loggedIn ? "Logout": "Login"} onPress={login}/>
}

function Content() {
  const loggedIn = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <>
    { loggedIn ? <Text>User is logged in</Text> : <Text>Please log in</Text> }
  </>
}

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={loggedIn}>
    <Toolbar login={() => setLoggedIn(!loggedIn)} />
    <Content/>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default App
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/AuthFlow.tsx) for the proper implementation.